# The median is not matching and going out of the box plot in SNS

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot, median

I have a problem with my box plot and I cant figure out how to make it work. It works for other data frames I have in my code but for this one is not. There are no nan values nor 0 in the data frame. So I dont know what might be.

```
combined_dfs1 = pd.DataFrame ({'GE 3.2 130': df_GE_32_130_mean,
                             'GE 3.4 130': df_GE_34_130_mean,
                             'GE 5.3 158': df_GE_53_158_mean,
                             'Nordex N131': df_Nordex_N131_mean,
                              'SG 4.1 142': df_SG_41_142_mean,
                              'SG 4.5 145': df_SG_45_145_mean,
                              'Vestas V90': df_Vestas_V90_mean,
                              'Vestas V100': df_Vestas_V100_mean,
                              'Vestas V110': df_Vestas_V110_mean,
                             'Vestas V136': df_Vestas_V136_mean,
                             'Vestas V150': df_Vestas_V150_mean})

box_plot = sns.boxplot(data = combined_dfs1)

ax = box_plot.axes
lines = ax.get_lines()
categories = ax.get_xticks()

for cat in categories:
    # every 4th line at the interval of 6 is median line
    # 0 -> p25 1 -> p75 2 -> lower whisker 3 -> upper whisker 4 -> p50 5 -> upper extreme value
    y = round(lines[4+cat*6].get_ydata()[0],1) 

    ax.text(
        cat, 
        y, 
        f'{y}', 
        ha='center', 
        va='center', 
        fontweight='semibold', 
        size=10,
        color='black',
        bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'))
    
box_plot.set( xlabel = "Different wind mills", ylabel = "Anually averaged wind capacity factors")
plt.title("Anually averaged wind capacity factors over the different \n wind mills suppliers with the most CF")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
box_plot.figure.tight_layout()
```

The content of each of the means it would be something similar to this data frame:

```
time    CF
2005    0.2627484028342433
2006    0.2824635223048327
2007    0.2675500697026022
2008    0.2911540057636888
2009    0.2762751475865262
2010    0.28497178538390383
2011    0.27058531492866256
2012    0.26133452904420273
2013    0.27250318397591755
2014    0.2781640652098508
2015    0.2671843141797961
2016    0.27489229696758455
2017    0.283594425087108
2018    0.267121473536955
2019    0.2582981070723493
2020    0.2753802263802264
```

[image]

Comment: What are the values/contents of `df_GE_32_130_mean`, etc.? Pls provide enough data to replicate the problem. Also, kindly explain your question/issue

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I added the content of the data frame

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works.

Comment: While creating `y`, you are rounding it to one digit and then plotting. So, y is usually 0.3. Try increase the round to 2 or 3 digits and see if you get what you need